# strange PHP session variable and caching issues starting today 14 Aug 2020

Tags: php, variables, session, caching

I have a site with pages built using PHP on the server. Yesterday, I activated a firewall for the site. This site is hosted on GoDaddy. The site is a club management system and I have over 80 clubs using it. Each club is their own "tenant" in the database.

Yesterday afternoon, I received a report that a user accessed a page that showed a different club, not their own. I received more reports of this situation this morning.

I use $_SESSION variables to control which "tenant" a user can access in the system. From what I can tell, it seems like the server is handing back session variables that do not belong to the user.  I'm using a PHPSESSID cookie for session management.

I'm also finding that my PHP pages seem to be caching, even on pages where I have this no-cache directive at the start of the script/page.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT');
```

If I add a random parameter (?foo=bar) to the URL and refresh the page, a fresh page loads for me.

I'm racking my head against the wall here.  Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? I will buy someone a bunch of coffee if they can help here. :-)

Comment: both could be related (caching and some user seeing a previously cached page for another tenant).. my guess you enabled some kind of caching on godaddy, reverse proxys dont have to adhere to Cache-Control: headers, like on cloudflare you can set what you want to do regardless of code set headers

Comment: Disable the firewall?

Comment: From my side, I simply clicked a button to activate the Firewall service that is available in my hosting package. I was surprised to see that it had not been activated previously. I guess this action did trigger some sort of caching. Any ideas to investigate further?  The GoDaddy support is not that helpful.  :-/  Seems like I want to leave the firewall in place as its a layer of protection, right?

Comment: yeah apparently the WAF/firewall includes a caching component, https://uk.godaddy.com/help/change-my-cache-level-32307

Comment: Yes, I just found these settings and I changed to "Disabled" and I did a Clear Cache too.  Let's see if this fixes things.

Comment: Looks like this may have helped!  Now researching Site caching (using your site headers) vs. Disabled (use with caution)